# What labels to use for a Simple and Advanced view of financial related information?

Tags: terminology, labels

I am creating a page that displays information about companies listed on a stock exchange. One of the views is going to be Simple, showing only a limited view of information and data while the other view will have more Advanced information that will only be of interest to financial experts.

When the webpage loads it will default to Simple view, and I will have a toggle to display the Advanced view.

What labels - other than Simple or Advanced - should I use as to be most accurate, whilst not offending either audience?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider:
- Simple / Detailed
- Overview / More Details

Make sure that the current view is clearly indicated (underling, state selected) and that both are put one next to the other (almost like a tab view).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the Advanced view is just more detailed of simple view in your case. So, I am not sure if "toggle" is the right type of frame used for this situation. I would rather see the current(simple) view titled what the page actually does. I am not sure exactly what the page title would be for you, but for the sake of this conversation:

A user is looking at a financial overview page which visualize the overview with a light explanation. This page is called "Finance Overview".

then a user clicks on "view detail" button to view more complex version of the overview content in detail.

Hope this helped.